# How to cast ItemsPanelRoot to SwapChainPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, 3d, uwp, itemscontrol

I was using HelixToolkit on UWP platform. Recently I am trying to change some of its features so I wrote a new viewport, imitating one in the HelixToolkit. Here is a problem I encountered that did not happen in HelixToolkit.

To create a SwapChainPanel in the Viewport(a class derived from ItemsControl class) , HelixToolkit directly convert ItemsPanelRoot into SwapChainPanel.

```
this.d3dTarget = new SwapChainTarget((SwapChainPanel)this.ItemsPanelRoot, this);
```

However, when my code come to this line, the runtime pops an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' to type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel'.

Pausing right before the casting, I see
[image]
Why is it showing StackPanel?

And if I pause before the HelixToolkit one, it shows a bunch of internal exceptions.

What could be the cause between these two differences? And is there an alternative way to create a swapchain in a wrapped up way to contain other items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you quoted doesn't create the `SwapChainPanel`, it simply retrieves the `SwapChainPanel` that was put in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

This is happening here: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/d386c9e1313ae1bbb1c179a17007e9b59ae221a6/Source/HelixToolkit.UWP/Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="controls:Viewport3DX">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <SwapChainPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to reproduce the same behavior, make sure the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of your `ItemsPanel` is set accordingly.

Comment: I see, there is indeed a Xaml file that I have overlooked, I'll have a try right away.